# iOS : Issue in accessing internet when app is launched from BGAppRefreshTask |BGProcessingTask

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

**Use case** : We want to update our app content while the app is in the background. We want to download some json data from our backend server(HTTP GET) and update the content of the application so that next time when user launches the app he see updated content. We are using apple’s BackgroundTasks framework API, specially BGAppRefreshTask and BGProcessingTask. Pretty standard

**Problem** → HTTP request via URLSession does not work.

We register and schedule BGAppRefreshTask and BGProcessingTask. Our application is launched in the background by iOS. But when we make an HTTP request to a web server, we do not get any response callback.
With default configuration, after making the request the response callback or the URLSessionDataDelegate methods are not called at all.  (I also tried with google url. just to be sure the problem is not only with our backend) .
Every thing works fine when I check entire flow while debugging and I am connected to Xcode and trigger a background launch by using this command
e -l objc --  (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"com.background_cloud_sync_apprefresh"]
I am kind of stuck with this issue and have run out of ideas to try.
So I am reaching out to expert here if you have faced any such issue on iOS.

I have tried URLSession with callback as well as with URLSessionDataDelegate.

UPDATE: Further findings. I also found out that the problem may be that the thread in which the background execution is called is not waiting for the URLSession request to complete. I verified it by putting few 1 sec thread sleep and give a separate queue to URLSession for delegate callback.
Question: How to make the background execution wait for the other async task to be finished.

Comment: Is your URLSession configured for background? CompletionBlocks/async/await methods won't work on it, you need to use Delegate. What's your delegate code? You need to show more code to help us understand what's going on.

Comment: No. But I tried with background configuration and for data task it is not working.

Comment: It's hard to tell without code what's wrong. I haven't tested but there is https://github.com/yorkepb/sample-background-refresh and Apple has a sample app: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/refreshing_and_maintaining_your_app_using_background_tasks

Comment: Please share your code to make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

to make your application keep processing the information in the background, you need to update the configuration from default to:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier:
                               "com.yourapp.bundleidentifier")
```

You can have more detailed information about this on this very nice tutorial about URLSession

Comment: A link to "this very nice tutorial " is missing.

Comment: @khyariMed I tried the background configuration but they does seem to work with the data task for get method.